# How to document parameter of class type extending another class with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc

Suppose I have this  javascript code that defines a class. One of its static methods returns a class with which to instantiate children.

```
class ParentClass {
  /**
   * Creates an instance of parent class
   *
   * @param {string} type - the type of the instance.
   */
  constructor(type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a child class.
   *
   * @param {string} type - the type.
   *
   * @returns {class<ParentClass> ?? ----- WHAT GOES HERE?? -----} the resulting class.
   */
  static createChildClass(type) {
    return class extends ParentClass {
      constructor() {
        super(type);
      }
    };
  }

}
```

I am using the eslint plugin `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` to check the JSDoc comments in the code.

My question is: what is the correct way to document a type (either in a `@param` or `@returns`) which is a class that extends from another class? In other words, how do I document the `@returns` marked in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsdoc [does not document](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) any special syntax for representing a type that extends a class.

On the one hand, you might get by just using `ParentClass` as the type (implying that this interface is what is returned)--considering that jsdoc is really a documentation tool rather than a strict type checker (and JavaScript methods more often than not just expect a particular (duck-typable) interface rather than imposing `instanceof` checks or such).

However, you could give a more precise definition of your return type like such, using the [`@augments`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-augments.html) tag (also available in jsdoc as `@extends`, and required as such in [Closure](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#extends-type)):

```
class ParentClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Creates a child class.
   *
   * @param {string} type - the type.
   *
   * @returns {ChildClass} the resulting class.
   */
  static createChildClass(type) {
    /**
     * @class ChildClass
     * @augments ParentClass
     */
    return class extends ParentClass {
      constructor() {
        super(type);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

(IIRC, though jsdoc doesn't document use of brackets with `@extends` as Closure apparently requires, I believe it may work with the brackets.)

Note that this is still a bit of a hack, however, as we are not documenting that a particular *instance* is returned, but we want to document that a whole class is returned. See https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1349 for an unimplemented issue. (TypeScript allows `typeof` with types, e.g., `@returns {typeof ChildClass}`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Google Closure type syntax (which JSDoc supports), you can document a class as the type of the constructor function (which it really is under the covers).

```
@param {function(new:SomeClass, arg1, arg2)}
```

See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System for more detail.